# Error in data[[grp[i]]] : subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to use `bwtrim` function from package `WRS2` to do a ANOVA but it returns the following error.

```
bwtrim(formula = Sumarea ~ Snumber * Day, id = id, data = CO2)
```

> Error in data[[grp[i]]] : subscript out of bounds

As far as I understood from other questions of this website (like [Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, , subscript out of bounds subscript out of bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29222524/error-in-tmp-subscript-out-of-bounds-subscript-out-of-bounds)), I am trying to call a non existance column. However, every column I typed is existing in my database.

```
> head(CO2)
    Sname Snumber Day Replica Diff Area Sumarea id
1 H4.8AxB       1   0       1    0    0       0  1
2 H4.8AxB       1   0       2    0    0       0  2
3 H4.8AxB       1   0       3    0    0       0  3
4 H4.8AxB       1   0       4    0    0       0  4
5    S141       2   0       1    0    0       0  5
6    S141       2   0       2    0    0       0  6
> tail(CO2)
       Sname Snumber Day Replica Diff  Area Sumarea  id
511 II-1Q61L      14  28       3  400 12530   34505 511
512 II-1Q61L      14  28       4    0     0   40348 512
513    Straw      15  28       1   20   140     790 513
514    Straw      15  28       2  120   875    7435 514
515    Straw      15  28       3  130   700    7925 515
516    Straw      15  28       4  130  1050    8935 516
```

I have also tried to use `sppbb` from the same package, returning a different error.

```
sppbb(formula = Sumarea ~ Snumber * Day, id, CO2, est = "onestep", nboot = 500)
```

> Error in xmat[, k] <- x[[kv]] : 
>         number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

My last attemp was using `mranova` function to analyze a subset of my db.

```
c1 <- subset(CO2, subset = Snumber == "1")
```

> Error in data.frame(y, groups, blocks) : object 'Sumarea' not found

The column does exist in my db indeed.

```
 Sname Snumber Day Replica Diff Area Sumarea  id
1   H4.8AxB       1   0       1    0    0       0   1
2   H4.8AxB       1   0       2    0    0       0   2
3   H4.8AxB       1   0       3    0    0       0   3
4   H4.8AxB       1   0       4    0    0       0   4
61  H4.8AxB       1   3       1 1210 1815    1815  61
62  H4.8AxB       1   3       2 2150 3225    3225  62
63  H4.8AxB       1   3       3 1600 2400    2400  63
64  H4.8AxB       1   3       4 1910 2865    2865  64
117 H4.8AxB       1   4       1 6280 3745    5560 117
118 H4.8AxB       1   4       2 6990 4570    7795 118
119 H4.8AxB       1   4       3 6440 4020    6420 119
120 H4.8AxB       1   4       4 6150 4030    6895 120
177 H4.8AxB       1   5       1 3820 5050   10610 177
178 H4.8AxB       1   5       2 5420 6205   14000 178
179 H4.8AxB       1   5       3 4780 5610   12030 179
180 H4.8AxB       1   5       4 5310 5730   12625 180
237 H4.8AxB       1   6       1 2320 3070   13680 237
238 H4.8AxB       1   6       2 2700 4060   18060 238
239 H4.8AxB       1   6       3 1900 3340   15370 239
240 H4.8AxB       1   6       4 2520 3915   16540 240
297 H4.8AxB       1   7       1 1240 1780   15460 297
298 H4.8AxB       1   7       2 1870 2285   20345 298
299 H4.8AxB       1   7       3 1350 1625   16995 299
300 H4.8AxB       1   7       4 1480 2000   18540 300
361 H4.8AxB       1  10       1  460 2550   18010 361
362 H4.8AxB       1  10       2  910 4170   24515 362
363 H4.8AxB       1  10       3  810 3240   20235 363
364 H4.8AxB       1  10       4  770 3375   21915 364
425 H4.8AxB       1  14       1    0    0   27975 425
426 H4.8AxB       1  14       2  820 3460   27975 426
427 H4.8AxB       1  14       3  580 2780   23015 427
428 H4.8AxB       1  14       4  530 2600   24515 428
```

I would be really grateful to anyone that suggest me a solution for my statistical analysis in general, and more specifically to get the `bwtrim` function working.
I think this mixed model is the one I have to use for my data (within-subject-variable = replica, between-subject= Strain, and Time, which I do no tknow where to place)

Comment: Please specify the packages used

Comment: Do examples in help files for this function run for you? If yes, then there may be something particularly different with your data. Perhaps you have a column with only one value...

Comment: @akrun I used only WRS2 package

Answer (score 2):

To me the solution was to remove unused factor levels in my between factor. These resulted from subsetting.

So may you check what your data looks like with:

`str(data)`

For the factors you could check if you have unused levels by comparing:

`nlevels(data$factorcolumn)`

with

`length(unique(data$factorcolumn))`

If they differ you could drop unused levels with

`data$factorcolumn <- droplevels(data$factorcolumn)`